# Time Series Forecast using LSTM and Neural Network

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm

I am doing a univariate time series forecast using Keras. The first Image shows forecasts using a neural network and the second image shows forecasts using an LSTM model. The models have been trained on the same number of training points for a particular period and then tested to make sure both the loss curves converge.

My question is why am I getting such different forecasts. I would like to know if this has anything do to with the nature of how both models operate? When making a forecast, I am using the last observation (transformed as a sequence of 5 columns), making a forecast, and that forecast value feeds back as a training point to generate a new forecast point.

Let me know if you need more information. Unfortunately, I cannot share too many details. But I can provide more context around the code. TIA[image: Forecasts]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.